# processing heterogeneous vectors in (C++-AMP)

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-amp

I've written code that read and parse variable number of .dat files and store them into 2D vectors, each file in separated vector. Now, I'm trying to take advantage of parallel processing (GPU) in order to perform some calculations on these vectors. However, many enquiries still ambiguous for me and I'd appreciate it if you can clarify them to me.

1. Do I have to define the `extent`s dimensions when I declare? since I have variable number of dimension based on the file. or can I can declare `extent` without declaring the dimensions like `concurrency::extent<2> eA;` if not, what would be alternative option?
2. When I declare `array<T,N>`; can I use `T` as generic type (e.g. using `boost::any`) since my vectors are heterogeneous (some numbers and some texts)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) No it is not possible to set the dimensions of an extent at runtime. It is a template parameter and must be set at compile time. You can only set the size of each dimension at runtime.

An alternative would be to declare a one dimensional array and then unpack the various dimensions manually using index offset math within your C++ AMP lambda.

2) No. C++ AMP is limited to a subset of types that the GPU can handle. You cannot use boost::any.

> A C++ AMP-compatible function or lambda can only use C++
>   AMP-compatible types, which include the following:

```
- int
- unsigned int
- float
- double
- C-style arrays of int, unsigned int, float, or double
- concurrency::array_view or references to concurrency::array
```

Without further description of your problem its hard to offer more advice.